# Are limiting and stationary distributions of a Markov chain always unique?

Tags: probability-theory, probability-distributions, markov-chains

Firstly am I correct in saying that that for an irreducible, aperiodic, positive recurrent Markov chain, a limiting distribution exists, and this distribution is the same as the chain's stationary distribution? (i.e solve $\pi P=\pi$ to find the limiting distribution).

Also, is it true that the limiting and stationary distributions of a Markov chain are always unique? My guess is yes, since we know that solutions to $\pi P=\pi$ are unique up to scalar multiplication, hence if $\pi$ is a distribution then this must mean it is the unique stationary distribution of the chain.

Comment: Yes to the first paragraph: A DTMC that is irreducible, aperiodic, and positive recurrent must have a stationary distribution, and it is the same as the limiting probaiblity, regardless of the initial state.  For second paragraph: If the chain is not irreducible, it may have several stationary distributions, and limiting probaiblities can depend on initial conditions. Consider a 3-state chain where state 1 goes equally likely to states 2 or 3, but once in 2 we stay in 2 always, once in 3 we stay in 3 always.

Comment: @Michael That looks like an answer to me.

Comment: @Michael thanks for the help. So would this mean that for an irreducible Markov chain on an infinite state space, its stationary distribution is unique (or does the chain have to be positive recurrent for this to be true)?

Comment: If a DTMC has a finite or countably infinite state space, is irreducible, and has a stationary distribution, then the stationary distribution must be unique and it must be positive recurrent (regardless of aperiodic).